# Point within polygon using pointfromtext and geometry o multipolygon

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial-query

I want to identify given point is in which polygon. i am using mysql database. Point is from text and multipolygon is in Shape column as geometry.i am using following query.

```
SELECT ap.ac_name
FROM andrapradesh ap
WHERE ST_Contains(PointFromText('POINT(16.504181 78.161779)'), ap.SHAPE)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use ST_Contains()  You should use

```
SELECT ap.ac_name 
FROM andrapradesh ap
WHERE ST_Contains(ap.SHAPE, PointFromText('POINT(16.504181 78.161779)');
```

> ST_Contains(g1, g2)
>
> Returns 1 or 0 to indicate whether g1 completely contains g2. This
>   tests the opposite relationship as ST_Within().

If you want use the contained  element as  first param  you need  ST_Within

```
SELECT ap.ac_name 
FROM andrapradesh ap 
WHERE ST_Within(PointFromText('POINT(16.504181 78.161779)'),ap.SHAPE);
```

> ST_Within(g1, g2)
>
> Returns 1 or 0 to indicate whether g1 is spatially within g2. This
>   tests the opposite relationship as ST_Contains().

Comment: You comment is not clear  . .. my answer at your question about ST_Contains work or not  ..  ?

Comment: my question is given point is is which area polygon. and ST_Within is not working

Comment: You question  .. use  ST_Contains and not ST_within  ..  and you are using ST_Contain in wrong way ..  first argument  is the  container second is the contained ..    and if you want the firts argument  the contained  the use ST_within and not ST_Contains as in you question code  .. answer  updated

Comment: i used the this now. but i am getting empty results. and shape is not polygon in table. it is geometry type..

Comment: then you should check the real coord for the polygon and the point ..  are you sure the polygons coords are in a valid Coordinate System Reference  (SR) coherent with SR for the point???  .. try build a polygon using text too with valid four point

Comment: yah i have given 4326 as projection. database aswell same projrction

Comment: try build the polygon as text  ( a simple square) ..  and check  .. .. remeber that    also the POINT must be in Coherent SR  ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes I Got Output. What id did is i chat lat and long.

```
SELECT ap.ac_name 
FROM andrapradesh ap 
WHERE ST_Within(PointFromText('POINT(78.161779 16.504181)'),ap.SHAPE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ST_Intersection(g1, g2)
```

Returns a geometry that represents the point set intersection of the geometry values g1 and g2. If any argument is NULL, the return value is NULL.

```
mysql> SET @g1 = ST_GeomFromText('LineString(1 1, 3 3)');
mysql> SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('LineString(1 3, 3 1)');
mysql> SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(@g1, @g2));

+--------------------------------------+
| ST_AsText(ST_Intersection(@g1, @g2)) |
+--------------------------------------+
| POINT(2 2)                           |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in detail

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.

Comment: Okey andrew Sorry